# Configuring Umbraco with MySQL: "Could not connect to database"

Tags: c#, mysql, umbraco

I am trying to install Umbraco for the first time, and I am using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5hKnDI0NIw&list=PLLYO0Qmbv5pvGjpI6Cyg3mVBoYtG_LK63). I want to use MySQL instead of MS SQL (which is not shown in the tutorial).

When using the installation wizard, this is the result:

[image: Umbraco installation wizard]

The error logged in `UmbracoTraceLog.txt` is:

> Configured database is reporting as not being available!. Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

MySQL is up and running, and I ended up trying the root user just in case it was a permissions issue. I wounder if the table `umbraco-cms` should already be filled (what would then be the point of the wizard? and where do I find that info?).

I have searched quite a lot about how to install Umbraco using MySQL but I haven't found the necessary info. [Other posts](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/4904-Configure-Umbraco-using-MySQL) indicate that it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Did you create the database "umbraco-cms" first? The wizard will create all tables when it installs.

Comment: @MortenOC I did, but maybe I did not configure the collation correctly or something similar. But it is already good to know for sure that the database "umbraco-cms" needs to be created beforehand in MySQL.

Comment: @MortenOC After digging a little deeper, I've found that my error was in the server address. Umbraco didn't like "127.0.0.1:3306", but I tried "localhost" (without port number) and it worked.

Comment: Cool you got it to work! :)

Comment: Just a extra note: I use USBWebserver for MySQL. I got the same error. In my case, the connection of the USBWebserver uses port 3307, so changed this to port 3306 will fix this.